# How can I get the duration, resolution of a video file programmatically in Android?

Tags: android

I hope to get the duration, resolution of a video file of a video (.mp4), how can I do that programmatically in Android ? My minSdkVersion is  21 .

BTW, I can get the file size of a video using the following code.

```
String recVideoPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + videoRecordedFileName;

File file = new File(recVideoPath);
long fileVideo = file.length();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To get duration and resolution `MediaMetadataRetriever` could be used like:

```
MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
retriever.setDataSource(uriOfFile);
long duration = Long.parseLong(retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION))
int width = Integer.valueOf(retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_WIDTH));
int height = Integer.valueOf(retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_HEIGHT));
retriever.release();
```

uriOfFile is a string with the url to you mp4.

Comment: Thanks!  mp should release, or it will occur error. so I add mp.release()

Comment: how to get uriOfFile from uri?